# How to send email with attachment of self-defined file extension name through Amazon?

Tags: c#, mime

I'm trying to send an email with attachment of self-defined file extension name, like 'file.aaa'. I don't know how to set it's MIME content type. I new an atachment as 'new Attachement(stream, null, null)'. But then got an Amazon exception of 'Illegal file name file.aaa'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify a MIME type in email.  You can use `application/octet-stream` to specify it should be handled as a binary file, `text/plain` for a text file or you can make your as `application/vnd.yourcompany.yourapplicationname` - anything that starts with `type/vnd.company` are reserved for private use.  See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) for more info.

---

Apparently, Amazon restricts both file extensions and MIME types.  I would consider zipping your custom format as apparently that is allowed.  See the [developer documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mime-types.html) for more.

```
var inputfile = "foobar.aaa";
var tempdir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
var outZipFile = File.GetTempFileName();

File.Move(inputfile, tempdir);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempdir, outZipFile);
Directory.Delete(tempdir, true /* delete the file within */);

var attachment = new Attachment(outZipFile, "yourFile.zip", "application/octet-stream");
// send your email
File.Delete(outZipFile);
```

Comment: The problem is I can only find MIME content type for common file extension names like '.txt', '.image', '.exe' or any other common extensions. But what is the correct content type for a self define file extension? I tried application/octet-stream, it doesn't work. I still got an AmazonSimpleEmailException of Illegal file name...